# Concurrently send bytes coming from stream to two destinations

Tags: go, concurrency, stream, channel

What's the best way to broadcast values from a stream to two network destination simultaneously? Here is simplified code:

```
func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://origin.com/image.jpeg")

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    // tee, when read, writes to &buf
    respBodyTee := io.TeeReader(resp.Body, &buf)

    sendToClient(respBodyTee)
    uploadeToServer(&buf)
}
```

A stream cannot be read twice, so `TeeReader` is used to populate `&buf` with whatever is read from `respo.Body`.

However, the functions (`sendToClient` and `uploadToServer`) will run synchronously while I'd like to them to make their work concurrently.

Solution that I have on mind is to pass a channel to `sendToClient` that will populate channel with bytes already sent to client. Later have `uploadToServer` read from the same channel. Something along these lines:

```
func main() {
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://origin.com/image.jpeg")

    ch := make(chan byte)
    go sendToClient(respBodyTee, ch) // pass 'ch' for writing and run in a goroutine
    uploadeToServer(ch) // will read from 'ch' (synchronous)
}
```

I'm new to Go and am not sure if the above is the right direction.

Comment: What happens if one of your consumers gets far ahead of the other? If you don't want them to be synchronous, you need some sort of buffering. It might be possible/sufficient to use bufio. Or you might need something much more complex, depending on your needs, and the potential sizes of these streams.

Comment: The simplest solution (although not the most performant) would probably be to write your stream to a disk. Then you can have an unlimited number of readers reading off the disk.  A more complex solution would be to use a disk-backed buffer.

Comment: @Flimzy you're right it's really tricky to cater for situations where one consumer gets ahead of the other at random. I went for copying the stream and working with them independently from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your scenario, it's better to have 2 independent byte streams for 2 network calls. If they rely on one source stream, when `sendToClient` stalls `uploadeToServer` will hang. channel wouldn't solve the problem above but introducing locking overhead.

you can try `io.MultiWriter` to make 2 independent byte streams

```
var buf1, buf2 bytes.Buffer
mw := io.MultiWriter(&buf1, &buf2)

if _, err := io.Copy(mw, r.Body); err != nil {
    ...
}
go sendToClient(buf1)
go uploadeToServer(buf2)
...
```

Comment: I tried to avoid copying the source stream initially, but later found that it's really tricky if copying is not involved. I like this approach better now. Thanks ;)

Comment: @owlwalks, what if we were dealing with a stream that could be multiple Gbs of data?  This wouldn't work for me since I can't load this much memory. How would you suggest doing it in this case?